# twilio video beta - conversations client returns null

Tags: webrtc, twilio

Just starting this morning, in any Twilio video Chrome-based client (Firefox works fine), I'm getting a "***TypeError: Cannot read property 'cause' of null***" after passing along the access manager identity and token. It's worked for months up until now.

I tried out a few older versions of the conversations client, but it still happens in Chrome and can't connect. I have an IP messaging text chat session piggybacking on the same token, but that works fine (and has for months).

Is there a way to validate a token? Any other issue that comes to mind?

Comment: Do you have some example code for how you're creating the access token and using it in the front end? Thanks

Comment: Nicely enough, it doesn't produce any errors when I tried it about 12 hours later in Chrome. No updates to Chrome or the server-side system that it's on. Assuming that maybe it was something on Twilio's side of things? I checked the status page, but the seemingly-related services were up.

Comment: Huh, that is strange. If you want to investigate further, I recommend you [get in touch with support](https://www.twilio.com/help/contact) who can look into it for you. Glad to hear it is working again though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems as though this was an oddity but for others working with the Twilio Video JavaScript SDK you can manage the lifecycle of your tokens via the [API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/access-tokens) and [AccessManager](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/video/guide/identity#create-token).

```
// Create an AccessManager to manage our Access Token
var accessManager = new Twilio.AccessManager('$TWILIO_ACCESS_TOKEN');

// Create a Conversations Client and connect to Twilio's backend
conversationsClient = new Twilio.Conversations.Client(accessManager);
conversationsClient.listen().then(function() {
    console.log('Connected to Twilio!');
}, function (error) {
    console.log('Could not connect to Twilio: ' + error.message);
});
```

If an issue arises send those verbose error logs from console into Twilio via [this form](https://www.twilio.com/help/contact).